# Deploy C executable on PetaLinux for Rocket Chip on Zynq FPGA

Tags: c, linux, riscv, zynq, petalinux

I'm currently trying to **deploy** an **application** (simple c program) to the **Zynq ZedBoard**. 
I followed the [Rocket Chip on Zynq FPGAs](https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq) github page to generate all the necessary files, put them on a SD card and **boot PetaLinux**.

In the tutorial, a **pre-packed *hello*** application can be executed after booting

```
root@zynq:~# ./fesvr-zynq pk hello
hello!
```

I successfully managed to get to this point. However, i'm wondering **how i can deploy my own c code** to an executable that will appear in the internal filesystem like the ***hello*** one above.

Comment: download armhf tool chain, setup environment variables for cross-compiling for armhf, make all

Comment: Since you don't seem to know much about cross-compiling, or compiling in general, I assume your project is small and involves less 5 source files. If that is the case, just run `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead of `gcc`. Also something worth trying is to see if there's gcc on the board, if there is, you can just copy the whole project to the board and compile it there. If you are not missing dependencies, then that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @user3528438 for giving me the right hint. I'm writing this for future reference.

I was able to deploy and execute my own C application by doing the following:

**Write** my own **C code** i want to execute on the Rocket Chip.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello Rocket!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile** the code for the riscv architecture and **generate executable**. *This requires the riscv toolchain to be installed of course!*

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o myhello hello.c
```

**Copy** the generated myhello executable **on your sd card** that you insert in the ZedBoard.

Turn on the ZedBoard and login.

**Mount the sd card** to be able to access your myhello executable.

```
$ mkdir /sdcard
$ mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /sdcard
```

Change to the /sdcard directory and copy your executable to the /home/root directory. (This is where you find the standard hello executable)

```
$ cd ../../sdcard
$ cp myhello /home/root
```

Switch back to the /home/root directory and **execute your myhello file on the Rocket Chip** via the frontend-server!

```
$ ./fesvr-zynq pk myhello
```

This prints the expected output to the console.

```
Hello Rocket!
```